# Data types in PHP SOAP

Tags: php, python, soap

I'm having problems creating proper variables according to my WebService WSDL. I have implemented this simple feature in python succesfully using suds 0.4 SOAP library.

Python implementation (tracker is my SOAP client object that consumes wsdl):

```
c = self.tracker.factory.create("ns4:Text")
c.type = "text/html"
c.content = "my content goes here"
self.tracker.service.createComment(c)
```

**How do I implement this in PHP?** At first glance I didn't quite understand how to archieve this with the PHP SOAP extension. The "...factory.create("ns4:Text") seems convinient in python. I can examine the attributes of the object and easily pass it to my available functions.

Do I really need to define the object in PHP the following way:

```
$c->type = "text/html";
$c->content = "my content goes here";
$this->tracker->__soapCall('createComment',array($c));
```

This implementation expects that I know and will define all the attributes of the object. I have complex data types of +37 attributes, also nested. Only 4 of them are required, and I would like to pass it to server with only 4 attributes filled, but still as a complete object with all the attributes defined...?

Does this make any sense?

**In summary**: python creates me complete object from the wsdl file, how do I get this in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

PHP can use the WSDL file to generate an appropriate set of methods to which you can pass generic objects, arrays, or scalars as arguments. You can also specify which classes map to which methods (the `classmap` option), and which type declarations map to which serialization callback functions (the `typemap` option) by using the second parameter of the SoapClient class.

```
class doRequestMethod {
    public $id;
    public $attribute;
}

class theResponseClass {
    /* ... */
}

$options = array(
    'classmap' => array(
        'doRequest'   => 'doRequestMethod',
        'theResponse' => 'theResponseClass'
        /* ... */
    ),
    'typemap' => array(
        0 => array(
            'type_ns' => 'http://example.com/schema/wsdl_type.xsd',
            'type_name"'   => 'wsdl_type',
            'from_xml'     => function ($xml_string) { /* ... */ },
            'to_xml'       => function ($soap_object) { /* ... */ }
        )
        /* ... */
    )
)

$client = new SoapClient('/path/to/filename.wsdl', $options);

$request = new doRequestMethod();
$request->id = 0;
$request->attribute = "FooBar";
$result = $client->doRequest($request);

/* 
 * If 'dorequest' returns a 'theResponse' in the WSDL, 
 * then $result should of the type 'theResponseClass'.
 */
assert(get_class($result) === 'theResponseClass');
```

It's a lot of work, so I'd recommend subclassing SoapClient for your own use. Also, in order to make the code easier to debug, use PHP type-hinting on function and parameter arguments as often as possible. It prevents a whole class of bugs and it's worth the minor performance penalty.

Comment: I like your clean answer, but I dont understant typemap array keys it seems that wsdl_type_ns does not exists, but there is a type_ns. Is it a typo ?